# Reste-t-il en français des traces du système de cas du latin ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, linguistique, latin

Les différentes catégories de pronoms personnels — sujet, complément direct, complément indirect — sont en général décrites comme des survivances en français du système de cas du latin.

Pour mémoire

```
Je  |        Pronom personnel sujet        | Nominatif    
Me  |  Pronom personnel complément direct  | Accusatif    
Moi | Pronom personnel complément indirect | Datif
```

Y a-t-il d'autres ? Pourquoi celles-ci ont-elles survécu ?

Comment: Je confesse que je n'ai pas lu tout les commentaires, mais quand je fais Contrôle + F je ne trouve pas le mot "autrui". "Autrui" est cas régime, "autre" cas sujet, non?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Je ne vois que les pronoms personnels et relatifs : *je, me, moi* (et autres personnes) et *qui, que, dont*, ... Attention, la détermination des cas est un plus compliquée que ce que tu laisses supposer et ne suit pas vraiment les cas latins, plutôt les cas germaniques — il y a en gros un cas sujet et un [cas régime](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9gime_%28cas%29) qui a lui-même deux formes dont la distinction ne suit pas les cas latins ou allemands.

- Le cas sujet (*je*, *tu*, *il/elle*, *nous*, *vous*, *ils/elles*, *qui*) est clair : on l'utilise lorsque le pronom est sujet d'un verbe. « Je vois », « l'homme qui parle », ... Le cas sujet ne s'emploie que lorsque le pronom est seul sujet du verbe (avec [quelques subtilités](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1243/lui-peut-etre-sujet-mais-pas-moi)) : « Lui et moi sommes venus », « toi seul peux nous sauver »...
- Pour un attribut du sujet, on utilise *moi*, *toi*, *lui/elle*, *eux/elles* (les premières et deuxième personnes du pluriel n'ont qu'une forme à tous les cas). « C'est moi », ... Le pronom relatif est *que* sauf si le verbe est propositionnel (cette construction se présente rarement).
- Pour un complément d'objet direct, on utilise *me*, *te*, *le/la*, *les*, *que*, toujours placés avant le verbe. On peut appeler ce cas accusatif, ou régime atome. « Il me voit », « la langue que tu parles », ...
- Après une préposition, quelle qu'elle soit, on utilise les pronoms personnels *moi*, *toi*, *lui/elle*, *eux/elles* et le pronom relatif *lequel/laquelle/lesquels/lesquelles* (qui se contracte en *duquel/de laquelle/desquels/desquelles* après *de*, et en *auquel/à laquelle/auxquels/auxquelles* après *à*). On peut appeler ce cas datif, ou régime tonique. « À moi, de toi, pour lui, sans elle, avec eux, sur elles, par lequel, après laquelle, à cause desquels, ... »
- Pour un complément d'objet indirect qui n'est pas introduit par une proposition, les formes des pronoms personnels sont un panachage de l'accusatif (première et deuxième personne) et du datif (troisième personne) : *me*, *te*, *lui/elle*, *eux/elles*. « Il me parle », « il lui parle », ... Quant au pronom relatif, c'est une autre forme : [*dont*](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/emploi-du-pronom-relatif-dont).

Quant à pourquoi ces survivances, je leur vois quelques points communs :

- Ce sont des mots très courants. Il est plus facile de retenir quelques formes différentes pour quelques mots que des règles d'inflexion pour toute une catégorie de mots.
- Ce sont des mots isolés (contrairement par exemple aux déterminants) qui portent une part importante de sens. Il est donc logique qu'ils soient particulièrement sujets à variation.
- La variation du pronom peut aider à déterminer leur construction grammaticale ou leur antécédent, elle peut quelquefois décider des ambiguïtés. Par exemple : « Il parle estonien à sa femme. Elle le parle aussi, mais préfère lui parler en igbo. »

Pour le pronom relatif, l'ambiguïté est plus importante : la fonction grammaticale ne peut pas être déterminée par la position dans la proposition comme elle l'est d'habitude en français. Il est donc nécessaire de conserver une distinction morphologique. « La personne qui parle, la langue qu'il parle, la personne à laquelle il parle, la personne dont il parle, ... »

Si je puis me permettre un peu de spéculation pour terminer, je dirais que le cas sujet des pronoms personnels a tendance à disparaître. Dans la langue orale, on utilise de plus en plus la forme régime tonique en renforcement, tandis que la forme sujet est souvent contractée : « Moi j'suis cap', toi t'es pas cap' ». Sur le long terme, nous allons vers un seul cas, avec deux formes (*me/moi*, etc.) qui se distinguent moins par leur fonction grammaticale que par leur place par rapport au verbe. Pour ce qui est des pronoms relatifs, *qui* et *que* restent bien établis, mais les [complexités de l'usage de *dont*](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/emploi-du-pronom-relatif-dont) s'érodent quelquefois.

Comment: Effectivement, la « déclinaison » des pronoms personnels en français n'est pas un calque de leur ancêtre latin. L'exemple de « me » qui est effectivement un héritier de l'accusatif latin d'*ego* (et dont la forme est identique) mais qui est à la fois objet direct (*il me voit*) et indirect (*il me donne un livre*) est à cet égard instructif. Je ne suis pas un spécialiste et ne vais pas chercher à expliquer l'évolution en détail, mais il me semble évident que le fait que les pronoms aient une forme tonique en français « *Moi*, je pense que... » a influencé leur développement.

Comment: le cas du sujet n'est pas si clair, p. ex. « toi et moi voyons… » (à mettre en regard de l'Anglais *you and I see…*)

Answer (score 4):

En ancien français, le système casuel s'était déjà partiellement effondré, et les noms ne présentaient plus que deux cas : le *cas sujet* et le *cas régime*. Dans la plupart des cas, le mot n'a eu de descendance que sous sa forme au cas régime, mais il y a des exceptions. [Albert Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9gime_%28cas%29) en cite quatre : gars / garçon, pâtre / pasteur, nonne / nonnain et pute / putain. (Je dois avouer que je ne connaissais que le premier et le dernier de cette liste).

On peut donc voir ces doublets comme des traces du système casuel latin, même si les différentes formes s'opposent maintenant par leur sens plutôt que par leur fonction.

Comment: Copain/Compagnon aussi

Answer (score 0):

Je dirais les pronoms relatifs: qui, que, dont