# Emploi du pronom relatif « dont »

Tags: pronoms, prépositions, pronoms-relatifs

Le mot *[dont](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dont)* joue le rôle d'un pronom relatif qui est le complément de la préposition *de*.

> Je me souviens de ce livre. Le livre dont je me souviens.
>   Je vois la maison de Paul. Paul, dont je vois la maison.
>   Je parle de cela. Ce dont je parle.

Il existe pourtant une autre construction : *duquel* (*de laquelle*, *desquels*, *desquelles*), qui est une contraction de la préposition *de* et du [pronom relatif](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/reste-t-il-en-francais-des-traces-du-systeme-de-cas-du-latin/1238#1238) *lequel* (*laquelle*, *lesquels*, *lesquelles*). Comment s'opère la distinction entre *dont* et *duquel* ?

(Je sais faire la différence en tant que locuteur natif, mais même après la lecture du TLF, je serais incapable de l'expliquer.)

Comment: J'y ai pas encore réfléchi mais je pense que la distinction génitif/ablatif joue un rôle : cf. http://french.stackexchange.com/a/3214/79. *Duquel* (i.e. *de lequel*) n'est possible que pour l'ablatif et *dont* semble indiquer préférentiellement un génitif lorsqu'il y a ambiguïté.

Comment: Au passage, *L'enfant dont les parents sont fiers*, tiré de la réponse sus-mentionée est un parfait exemple d'ambiguïté.

Answer (score 14):

En première approximation *duquel* (*de qui* quand l'antécédent est une personne, *de quoi* quand l'antécédent est un pronom neutre) et *dont* sont presque interchangeables : *dont* n'est pas un pronom interrogatif, est obligatoire quand l'antécédent est *ce*, *cela* ou *rien* et ne peut dépendre d'un complément introduit par une proposition (*Le prochain à la réputation de qui le calomniateur nuit* doit être préféré à *Le prochain dont le calomniateur nuit à la réputation*).

Donc *dont* n'est obligatoire que dans ton troisième exemple, dans les deux autres *duquel* ou *de qui* est possible (personnellement j'utiliserais *dont* même si *duquel* et *de qui* ne me choquent pas).

Mais Grevisse continue après cette règle en écrivant :

> Mais la situation est plus complexe si l'on tient compte de la langue littéraire et de divers emplois figés.

et il passe une dizaine de pages à donner des règles suivies d'exceptions et d'exceptions aux exceptions (p.e. *la banque dont il est un des directeurs* est correct alors que *dont* dépend d'un complément introduit par *de*), sans parler des règles avec lesquelles il n'est pas d'accord et des exemples archaïsants ou d'auteurs ne respectant rien.

Ma perception est que les règles imposant l'un ou l'autre sont toujours en évolution et pas toutes bien fixées.

Comment: Vive les auteurs ne respectant rien!

Comment: @Joubarc, et sus aux prescriptivistes qui inventent des exceptions en plein vol pour essayer de les rattraper...

Answer (score 5):

Le CNLTR indique que :

> DONT, pronom relatif.
>   Pronom relatif des deux genres et des deux nombres introduisant une proposition relative à l'intérieur de laquelle il joue le rôle d'un complément prépositionnel introduit par de. Il est l'équivalent de de qui, duquel, de laquelle, desquels, desquelles lorsque l'antécédent, substantif ou pronom, désigne un être animé; de duquel, de laquelle, desquels, desquelles lorsque l'antécédent désigne un inanimé; de de quoi lorsque l'antécédent est un pronom neutre comme ce, cela, rien.

Dont est une sorte de généralisation.

Je me souviens de la cheminée de laquelle s'échappait la fumée. / Je me souviens de la cheminée dont s'échappait la fumée. (inanimé)

Je me souviens du chien duquel mes parents ont hérité. / Je me souviens du chien dont mes parents ont hérité. (animé)

Je me souviens de quoi j'ai reçu cette blessure. / Je me souviens de ce dont j'ai reçu cette blessure. (indéterminé)

Ces exemples traduisent l'explication trouvé dans une autre référence du CNTLR :

> Exprime aujourd'hui les divers rapports sémantiques marqués par la préposition de  et correspond à de qui, duquel, de laquelle, desquels, desquelles, de quoi.

Comment: C'est moi qui suis fatigué, ou tu ne réponds pas du tout à la question, qui est de savoir comment on choisit entre *dont* et *duquel* (et cie) ?

Comment: Je pense que la réponse sous-entend qu'on fait ce qu'on veut, ou que quand on ne sait pas quoi mettre entre _de qui_ et _duquel_, on prend _dont_.

Answer (score 0):

Je suis Angliche, mais j'étudie le français depuis des décennies.  Ce nom de "Grevisse" éveille en moi des souvenirs longtemps ensevelis sous la vie "réelle".
Pourtant, j'ai parmi mes livres un volume poussiéreux qui s'intitule "Larousse Difficultés" (...de la langue française).  Sous "lequel" je lis que (italique du livre):

- "[ces pronoms] s'emploient à la place de *qui* précédé d'une préposition quand l'antécédent est un nom de *chose*"
- "... à la place de *qui* pour éviter une équivoque ou la répétition d'un pronom"
- "... ne s'emploie pas après *et* (Grevisse)"

Plus simplement, je dirais que "dont" évoque une impression, voulue ou non, littéraire ou nom, ou autre ..., de "flou" : "La maison dont je me souviens"/"La maison de laquelle je me souviens".
Cette dernière phrase, à mes oreilles d'Anglo-Saxon, évoque une précision qui est la plupart du temps superflue, voire pompeuse.  Mais... au cours d'une longue discussion pendant laquelle on a passé en revue beaucoup de maisons différentes, quand on a peut-être un peu trop bu, par exemple, il n'est pas impossible d'imaginer que tel interlocuteur ait envie de *préciser* la maison concernée.

Comment: Je ne dirais pas « de laquelle je me souviens », et [je ne suis pas le seul](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=de+laquelle+je+me+souviens%2Cdont+je+me+souviens&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdont%20je%20me%20souviens%3B%2Cc0). Mais je ne vois pas le rapport avec une impression de flou.

Answer (score -1):

Comment choisir lorsque les règles grammaticales sont muettes, contradictoires, inopérantes ?

> Il y a des musiciens *dont* la musique émeut et réjouit mais qui ne connaissent rien du solfège ; d'autres ne sont parfois que de savants lecteurs de portées *desquels* (, ceux là) ne produisent que des sons rébarbatifs, inharmonieux, glauques.

*Dont*, s'utilise ici dans le sens général, anonyme, comme on utilise le *on* indéfini pour rester dans les grandes lignes d'un discours.

*Desquels* est plus ardu à écrire, car plus soutenu. Ici il évite la virgule, la coupure de la phrase et insiste sur une particularité de ce que *dont* désigne habituellement.

> De même l'oreille de certains francophones arrange des phrases *dont* la compréhension est limpide bien que bourrées de fautes d'orthographe lorsqu'elles noircissent la papier, et, de doctes grammairiens écrivent parfois *ces* phrases parfaites *desquelles* (*des* phrases parfaites *dont*) le vide, le creux, l'ennui, l'insipidité, l'hébétude émergent spontanément et oblitèrent l'entendement.

L'usage courant est d'utiliser *dont* lorsque le choix est possible : le *des* entre parenthèses ne signifie rien de précis par opposition au *ces* qui introduit le *desquelles* lui-même traduisant une intention appuyée de pointer ces ennuyeux phraseurs.

Sinon "Il y a des musiciens *desquels* ..." ou "... les phrases *desquelles* ..." risque de vous faire passer pour un fat, un pédant voire un fâcheux... ce qui peut être un choix pour se moquer d'autrui si on maîtrise l'art de l'ironie.

La distinction de l'usage *dont- duquel* n'est pas à chercher dans les savantes grammaires, dans l'étiquetage des mots, les différentes techniques de la tonte de œufs, mais dans les instants qui précèdent le verbe, avant la vibration sonore, cette intuition qui supporte l'art indéfinissable du texte, qu'il soit oral ou écrit.

Comment: Pourquoi -1 ? Est-ce que la francophonie est normalisée ? limitée par des règles dont certaines sont incertaines ?