# Le contenant dont/d'où/duquel est extrait ?

Tags: pronoms-relatifs

L'autre matin à la radio, l'animateur s'est emmêlé en parlant d'une chanson. Il a finalement dit : « Il s'agit du dernier album de Xxx *dont* est extrait le titre que nous venons d'écouter. »

Il a hésité, en disant « dont », puis « d'où », puis finalement « dont ».

Je me suis aussi posé la question.

- J'ai refusé « d'où » puisque la notion de lieu (liée à l'utilisation de *où*) pour un album musical ne me semble pas appropriée.
- J'ai accepté « dont » puisque équivalent à « de que » il me semble correct.
- J'aurais préféré « duquel » qui me semble plus pertinent.

Mais j'avoue ne pas savoir pourquoi je préfère *duquel* à *dont*.

Quelqu'un aurait-il une explication pour la version correcte ?

Comment: Pour *dont* et *duquel*, voir ici: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/emploi-du-pronom-relatif-dont

Answer (score 1):

Pour une approche très subjective, laisser le cerveau choisir le mot qui lui tombe sous la main : 
De récentes recherches en neurosciences ont démontré que le cerveau a déjà choisi et déclenché toutes les procédures servant à l'expression orale avant que l'on commence à ouvrir la bouche ; certains philosophes appellent cela le virtuel, les psy l'inconscient ... d'où la possibilité de *[lapsus linguae](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapsus_linguae)* lorsque le mental se rend compte qu'une erreur, un contresens, une absurdité a été prononcée.

Ce qui semble avoir été mis en œuvre lors de la reprise du mot par l'animateur, est la soumission du point de vue à l'opinion générale (est-ce que la phrase que je viens de dire est correcte, qu'est-ce qui me gêne? un autre mot synonyme est possible (celui auquel j'ai pensé lors de la préparation de l'émission) ; finalement je crois que suis en train de faire une faute de français, je me range derrière la doxa).

En effet :

> - L'album *dont* : C'est le point de vue de celui qui parle, au moment de sa phonation.
> - L'album *d'où* : C'est le point de vue de la source du discours, la valorisation du sujet.
> - L'album *duquel* : C'est le point de vue didactique qui maîtrise la communication.

L'auditeur peut percevoir l'orientation de la pensée sous-jacente, il est donc plus facile de choisir le mot qui convient au contexte au moment de l'écriture, lorsque le temps de la réflexion n'est pas compté.

Comment: Il y a une idée, mais elle n'est pas clairement formulée et noyée dans du hors sujet.

Comment: Je connaissais le lapsus linguae, le lapsus calumni, mais comment appelle-t-on un lapsus de frappe sur le clavier ? Le savant auteur de la réponse précédente en a fait un sur "gêne".

Comment: @MarkThorin Cela devrait s'appeler "correcteur orthographique en panne". Sans aucune référence, ma réponse ne peut être savante, c'est seulement un problème de scénario, de prise en compte du point de vue de l'acteur et des mouvements possibles.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Comment ne pas être 'hors sujet' lorsque la question porte sur la recherche de la *version correcte*, version qui dépend du contexte ; contexte qui dépend lui-même de l'expression orale d'un animateur qui est déstabilisé par un conflit de choix de mot sur une intervention apparemment sans prompteur ?  Il n’y a pas de ’bon’ choix par principe, seulement un façon personnelle d’entendre (d’interpréter) un texte, qui peut être modifiée par déplacement du point de vue. Pour l’interprète (ici l'animateur), ce choix engagera la construction de la suite de son discours.