# "Dont" vs "duquel" / "de laquelle"?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, pronoms-relatifs

> C'est la dame dont j'ai parlé.

I know that the above sentence is correct, but is it incorrect to say—

> C'est la dame de laquelle j'ai parlé.
>
> C'est le monsieur duquel j'ai parlé.

If so, why?

Comment: I read this from about.com: *What's the difference between dont and duquel? You need dont when the preposition you're replacing is de by itself. You need duquel when de is part of a prepositional phrase, such as près de, à côté de, en face de, etc.* But I'm really not clear on that.

Comment: En commençant une recherche pour répondre je suis tombée sur [cette question sur FrenchLanguage](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/1239/358) mais elle ne semble pas encore avoir eu de réponse satisfaisant celui qui a posé la question.

Comment: Mon Dieu, Gilles ne savait pas quelquechose sur la langue francaise?? Non!!!!!!!

Comment: quelque chose**

Answer (score 1):

In general in cases such as this, **dont** is interchangeable with **duquel** etc and, in the animate case, **de qui**. In practice, **dont** appears to be more common.

Principal cases where **dont** is strongly preferred are "neuter" cases such as **ce dont j'ai besoin**, or cases where **dont** specifies a whole clause (**un homme dont les yeux sont bleus/dont il me semble que je l'ai vu quelque part**). Note that informal or "popular" usage often allows a generic **que** in these cases.

Comment: I can't imagine anyone saying *un homme dont il me semble que je l'ai vu quelque part* it would be *un homme qu'il me semble avoir vu quelque part*, *dont* implies a "possession" relation ship. But you could say: *un homme dont je crois que les yeux sont bleux*.

Comment: Yes, it's a rarer construction. It is attested by *some* speakers, though. (But if that particular example doesn't work for you, presumably you still agree with the general point that "dont" specifying a clause is not interchangeable with "duquel" etc?)