# Quand on doit utiliser « duquel » au lieu de « dont » ?

Tags: pronoms-relatifs

Il me semble que *dont* est utilisé quand un pronom relatif serait précédé par la préposition *de*, c'est à dire, on utilise *dont* plutôt que *duquel*:

> On ne doit pas se prévaloir de la fortune.
>
> La fortune est un avantage *dont* on ne doit pas se prévaloir.

Mais mon prof, qui est français, m'a dit qu'on utilise *duquel* ici:

> Ils aiment longer le fleuve sur les bords *duquel* poussaient des roseaux.

Pourquoi est-ce comme ça? Quand puis-je décider d'utiliser *duquel*?

Comment: Duplicate https://french.stackexchange.com/q/11386/17649 https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1239/17649

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ton professeur a raison. Si, comme il est dit dans [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1241/358) *dont* et *duquel*  sont souvent interchangeables, ce n'est pas toujours le cas. Je ne vais pas répéter ce qui a déjà été dit par ailleurs mais me contenter de dire pourquoi l'emploi de *dont* n'est pas possible dans la phrase :

> Ils aiment longer le fleuve sur les bords duquel poussaient des roseaux.

Après une **locution prépositive** on n'emploie pas *dont* mais ***duquel*** (*desquels, de laquelle, desquelles*). Une locution prépositive est composée d'une ou de deux prépositions et d'un nom, d'un verbe ou d'un adverbe. *Sur les bords de*  est une locution prépositive. Il existe beaucoup de locutions prépositives, sur [cette page](http://mamiehiou.over-blog.com/2015/03/des-prepositions-et-des-locutions-prepositives.html) tu en trouveras une liste partielle mais une fois que tu auras compris ce que c'est tu les reconnaîtras.

Quelques autres exemples de phrases où l'emploi d'une locution prépositive entraîne l'emploi de *duquel* ou d'un de ses dérivés.

- Je vais te présenter les amis **avec l'aide desquels** j'ai pu finir de rénover le jardin.
- Nous allons fixer la date **à partir de laquelle** le bureau sera définitivement fermé.
- Voici la colline **en haut de laquelle** les cyclistes ont fait une pause.
- Les étudiants **à l'intention desquels** ce livre est écrit en apprécieront la clarté des exposés et la fluidité de la rédaction.