# What is an object of the verb 'De' for the use of 'Ce dont'?

Tags: prépositions

The object of a preposition would be like this:

*Avec quoi écris-tu ?*
(What do you write with?)

With *quoi* being the object of the preposition *avec* (with); however when you use the preposition *de* you must use *Ce Dont* instead of *quoi*.

In this example:

C'est ce dont je me souviens. 
(That's what I remember)

You never see the preposition *de*, anywhere in the clause. How is it an object of a preposition, which is not even present in the sentence? Whereas in the first example you see the preposition *avec* in the sentence.

Please explain!

Comment: Thanks for the correction, forgot hyphen, typing on mobile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Dont* means *de qui* (for people), *duquel* / *de laquelle* / *desquels* / *desquelles* (for identified things) or *de quoi* (for unidentified things). Depending on the context, you may have the choice of what to use, or one may be mandatory.  The two most important aspects of those rules is that:

- when asking a question, it is never *dont* (thus, *de quoi te souviens-tu?*, not <strike>*Dont te souviens-tu?*</strike>)
- after *ce*, it is always *dont* (thus, *c'est ce dont je me souviens*, not  <strike>*C'est de quoi je me souviens*</strike>)

See [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1239/176) for more details.