# Is this usage of dont correct?

Tags: pronoms-relatifs

In this sentence:

> Je suggère que nous réduisions notre usage de voitures et utiliser les transports en commun dont au lieu.

Is the usage of *dont* correct and can it be used in this way?

Comment: No, it adds nothing here. (To test it yourself, *dont* can almost always be translated either "whose" or "of which".) There are a couple of other issues with the sentence; not much time right now, but if I get a chance later on to answer properly before someone else does I'll do so.

Comment: Please do, my French is only at a basic level (learning at high school), and I'd love to learn more, especially about relative pronouns.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea about what you expect *dont* to mean in that sentence but it's definitely incorrect here.

Here is how I would rephrase it:

> *Je suggère que nous réduisions notre usage de voitures particulières et utilisions les transports en commun à la place.*

or

> *Je suggère de réduire notre usage de voitures particulières et d'utiliser les transports en commun à la place.*

Instead of *à la place*, you might also use *plutôt*:

> *Je suggère de réduire notre usage de voitures particulières et d'utiliser plutôt les transports en commun.*

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to use dont as a way to say ‘use public transport instead’ and I assumed you needed de after au lieu.

Comment: I understand. You can't use *au lieu* in this sentence. The English "in lieu", despite its obvious French origin, translates to *à la place* while *au lieu de...* translates to "instead of..."

Comment: @jlliagre The mistake lies rather in thinking that because "instead of X" can be translated « au lieu de X », therefore "instead" (the natural word to end this sentence in English) can be translated « au lieu » by capturing the implicit "de X" with a pronoun. In any case, I agree with the recommendation!

Comment: Thanks to both of you! If one of you wouldn't mind, could you check my French paragraphs once I've finished writing them. You both seem very competent in the language.

Comment: @user491194 Feel free to ask other questions about specific points you have trouble with.

Comment: Could you give me a comphrensive overview on relative pronouns. I understand qui/que, lequel and dont as individual ideas, but not when to use each one. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You would use *dont* or *duquel/de laquelle/desquels*when you use "whose" or "of which" in English. Selecting *dont* or the others can be complex. See https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/emploi-du-pronom-relatif-dont

Comment: Are you sure we can't use "au lieu" in this sentence? What if we just turn it around: "Je suggère d'utiliser les transports en commun au lieu de voitures particulières"

Comment: @LaurentS. What I meant is we can't use *au lieu* without significantly changing the sentence structure: *réduisions notre usage* is a show stopper for *au lieu*.

Comment: @LukeSawczak very nice explanation of the literal translation trap!