# « Lui » peut être sujet, mais pas « moi » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, histoire, origine-ou-raison, sujet

Intéressé par une précédente [question sur les pronoms](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1232/79), je me demandais pourquoi *lui* peut être sujet dans certains cas, et pas *moi* (je parle ici de groupes nominaux constitués d'un seul mot).

> Hélène, silencieuse, sentait les larmes couler le long de ses joues, Gaston sentait sa poitrine chargée d'un poids énorme, car *lui* ne pleurait pas […]

<sup>(J'ai eu un mal fou à trouver une citation qui ne soit pas biblique, car les textes religieux abusent abondamment de « lui ».)</sup>

On se rend compte que le même effet aux premières et deuxièmes personnes demande une répétition du sujet : « car moi, je ne pleurais pas ».
Au pluriel, la répétition est aussi nécessaire pour distinguer des *nous* et *vous* habituels : « nous, nous ne pleurions pas ».

Qu'est-ce qui peut expliquer que *lui* et *eux* peuvent échapper à la répétition, contrairement à *moi*, *toi*, *nous*, et *vous* ?

---

**Note :**
Étrangement, *moi seul* possède aussi cette capacité à devenir sujet, comme *lui*, ou *lui aussi*, ou *lui-même*, ou *lui seul* ; et contrairement à *moi*, ou *moi aussi*, ou *moi-même* :

> Car moi seul détiens le pouvoir — *(suivi d'un rire démoniaque :)* Ha… ha… ha… ha… ha.

Comment: @Stéphane, Grevisse décrit ce que tu observes (sauf pour _moi aussi_ et _moi-même_) mais ne donne pas d'explications et le paragraphe n'a pas de section historique.

Comment: @Unfrancophone: Je n'en avais as trouvé dans Grevisse non plus mais il y a des éléments historiques dans 
 *Histoire d'une langue : le français* (Marcel Cohen, 1973)  et *Expression et position du sujet pronominal : évolution en français*, (Sophie Prevost, CNRS, 2012) voir [ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/11328/358)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On peut dire que tous les pronoms toniques peuvent être employés comme sujets, mais que *toi* et *moi*, quand ils sont employés pour marquer l'opposition et que le verbe est exprimé, au contraire des autres pronoms toniques,  ne peuvent pas être employés seuls.
Ceci est une question d'usage qui pourrait s'expliquer par des raisons historiques. L'expression du pronom sujet en français est beaucoup plus ancienne pour les deux premières personnes du singulier que pour les autres personnes et est serait donc ancrée dans l'usage.

En latin les pronoms personnels sujets n'étaient pas exprimés, et quand  les pronoms de la 1<sup>re</sup> et 2<sup>e</sup> personne sont employés en fonction sujet, c'est pour insister sur la personne<sup>1</sup>.
Les pronoms sujets des 1<sup>re</sup> et 2<sup>e</sup> personnes commencent à être régulièrement employés à côté du verbe en ancien français dès le XI<sup>e</sup> siècle, en particulier pour marquer une opposition, alors que les autres personnes ne sont généralement pas employés.
Ce n'est qu'au XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle que l'expression du sujet devient la norme et que son absence commence à être condamnée.

Qui sait si dans quelques siècles, une phrase comme

> <del>Ils voulaient venir, mais moi voulais pas</del>.

ne sera pas considérée comme correcte ? Le français est une langue vivante, qu'elle vive!

<sup>1 *laboro* : je travaille, *ego laboro*  moi, je travaille</sup>.

Sources : *Histoire d'une langue : le français* (Marcel Cohen, 1973)
[Expression et position du sujet pronominal : évolution en français](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/66/51/83/PDF/prA_vost_SujProSLP_2011.pdf), (Sophie Prevost, CNRS, 2012)

Comment: J'accepte la réponse en espérant en savoir un peu plus un jour!

Answer (score 12):

[Le huitième dictionnaire de l'Académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/moi) liste les cas où *moi* peut être sujet

> MOI s'emploie comme sujet, à la place de Je :
>
> - dans une proposition elliptique : *Qui veut aller avec lui? Moi*. *Il est aussi fatigué que moi*. *Feriez-vous comme moi?*
> - dans une proposition dont le verbe est à l'infinitif : *Moi, trahir le meilleur de mes amis! Faire une lâcheté, moi!*
> - dans une proposition participe : *Moi parti, ils ont continué à délibérer*.
> - comme sujet réel : *Il n'y eut que moi de cet avis*.
>
> Il s'emploie en outre comme sujet coordonné à un nom ou à un autre pronom : *Mon avocat et moi sommes de cet avis. Son père, sa mère et moi, le lui avons défendu. Lui et moi l'avons ainsi décidé. Ni vous ni moi ne sommes contents de notre sort. Nous irons à la campagne lui ou moi*.

Dans beaucoup de cas, donc.

Quant aux cas où il ne peut pas l'être, je suis tenté d'aller chercher dans l'étymologie. D'après le [wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/moi)

> De l’ancien français *mei*, forme tonique de me, cas régime de jo, je « je »,

Le cas régime, de son petit nom *tout sauf le cas sujet*, me paraît être un bon candidat pour former un pronom ne pouvant pas toujours être sujet. Idem pour *toi* qui vient de l'accusatif *te*.

Je n'ai pas trouvé d'étymologie pour *lui* et *eux*, en revanche je ne comprends pas en quoi *nous* et *vous* ont un rapport.

Comment: Grevisse cite en plus au moins le cas où le pronom est séparé du verbe par plus que d'autres pronoms et _ne_. (Ce qui explique _moi seul détiens le pouvoir_, mais interroge sur l'impossibilité de _moi aussi détiens le pouvoir_).

Comment: Ok, c'est intéressant, mais je vais tenter de préciser ma question. Dans le cas que je cite, *moi* ne peut pas être sujet *directement* : « moi ne pleure pas » n'est pas possible. Il faut dire « moi, je ne pleure pas », et au pluriel ça donne « nous, nous ne pleurons pas ». En revanche, à la troisième personne, ça peut donner « lui, il ne pleure pas », mais *aussi* « lui ne pleure pas ». Cette contraction n'est pas possible aux 1ère et 2e personnes, et c'est la 3e personne qui semble jouer un rôle particulier dans cette affaire. Pourquoi ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Ok pour *lui*, je vais tâcher d'améliorer. Mais on peut dire « nous ne pleurons pas ».

Comment: Oui, mais « nous ne pleurons pas » ne met pas l'accent sur le contraste qui se forme avec les personnes précédemment citées. C'est compris de la même façon que « il ne pleure pas », et pas comme « lui ne pleure pas ». Il faut obligatoirement redoubler le sujet pour obtenir approximativement le même effet : « nous, nous ne pleurons pas ».

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: je viens de voir ton commentaire - j'avais zappé cette question à cause de son intitulé (moi pouvant bien sûr être sujet....) j'ai complété ma réponse à la [question de Hunter](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/11326/358) avec éventuellement une piste pour toi. De toute façon la raison est historique.

Answer (score 4):

Il me semble qu'en réalité "moi" peut être sujet, par exemple dans cette phrase:

> Moi qui ne pleurais pas sentais un poids énorme.

*(Ce n'est pas une citation, j'ai écrit cette phrase)*

Comment: En effet, ça me paraît possible d'utiliser *moi* comme sujet immédiat dans ce cas. La répétition est possible mais ne semble pas nécessaire. C'est un exemple intéressant car il n'y a pas d'ellipse, seulement une subordonnée qui s'intercale sans influence sur la phrase principale. En ce qui concerne l'orthographe : cf. [moi qui](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/549/moi-qui-fait-ou-moi-qui-fais) :-)

Comment: Ce n'est pas « moi » le sujet ici, mais « moi qui ne pleurais pas ». En gros, on utilise « je » lorsque c'est le seul mot du sujet, et « moi » dans tous les autre cas. En revanche, « lui » peut des fois s'utiliser comme seul mot du sujet.

Answer (score 0):

Peut-être tout simplement parce que *moi, toi, soi* se réfèrent à la conscience intime qu'une personne peut avoir d'elle-même alors que *lui* se réfère à la perception physique d'un autre corps qui ne peut être celui de *_oi.*

L'insupportable *moi je pense que...* affirme bien que ma conviction, ma sensibilité, mon mental (entités détachées des sens) ne sont pas la réalité sensible, physique, perceptible de mon corps et que j'ai besoin ce dernier pour communiquer par l'attitude ou la parole.

Alors que si *lui pense que ...*, je ne perçois que la manifestation de son ego à travers la physionomie et l'expression de son corps ; mais *lui qui pense que ...* renvoie à quelque chose que je devine, que je pressent de son intimité que je renforce par le *qui* pour bien détacher le sujet imaginé de l'objet réel.

- *_oi* comme référence à une entité abstraite ne peut être sujet, car il n'y a pas d'enracinement dans la réalité alors que *lui* en est un élément.
- *_oi* qui pointe vers un objet, une réalité peut devenir sujet comme certaines réponses le mentionne.

Ajouter un sujet à *_oi* ne dépend pas de règles grammaticales, mais de l'intention, de la cible que le locuteur évoque plus ou moins consciemment.