# Pronoms sujets : « elle et moi » ou « elle et je » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, sujet, compléments

Ces deux phrases sont-elles correctes ?

> Elle et moi aimons les fruits.

ou

> Elle et je aimons les fruits.

En anglais, la forme correcte utilise le cas sujet, pas le cas objet. En français, est-ce que la phrase reste correcte, grammaticalement, lorsque le pronom *moi* est substitué au cas sujet *je* ?

Comment: Ta première proposition est la seule qui soit correcte : « Elle et moi aimons les fruits. » La deuxième phrase est impossible.

Comment: Il est à noter que `moi` n'est pas le cas objet. Il s'agit d'un pronom disjoint, c'est à dire détaché des fonctions directement liées au verbe (sujet, objet). Dans votre example il sert à construire un sujet multiple.

Comment: note that the "correct" form in English used to be "me," and this is still the form that occurs in the spoken language of most of us. Unfortunately, self-appointed grammarians decided that English should be more like Latin and for hundreds of years have, with limited success, tried to make schoolchildren put "I" here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Après les prépositions: et, à, pour, de, chez, sur, etc. il est obligatoire d'utiliser le pronom tonique : moi, toi, lui... C'est pourquoi vous ne pouvez pas dire *Elle et je* même si les deux sont sujets de *aimons*.

En fait, si vous ajoutez *on*, comme mentionné antérieurement, vous modifiez un peu le sens de la phrase : vous faites emphase sur le sujet. Dans le premier cas vous énoncez simplement un fait.

**Elle et moi aimons les fruits.** Énoncé d'un fait; elle et moi = nous; on utilise moi au lieu de je car on a une préposition.

**Elle et moi, on aime les fruits** (oral familier - standard) / **Elle et moi, nous aimons les fruits.** (oral soutenu, écrit). Insistance sur le sujet plus que sur l'action. *Elle et moi* est obligatoirement suivi d'une virgule.

[Fiche sur les pronoms toniques.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwcwifEtTDfbTmdxTXJyMGFvNjA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Voir également le cas d'[un pronom sujet qui est complémenté par une subordonnée](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/1245/79), et le commentaire de Gilles.

Comment: Merci Fractaliste. Le format que j'avais donné au texte n'a pas été gardé. J'ignore pourquoi.

Answer (score 2):

En cas de sujets coordonnés, "**moi**" se substitue à "**je**", comme "**lui**" se substitue à "**il**".

> "<s>**Il** et **je**</s>" --> "**lui** et **moi**"

On rencontre plus souvent cette tournure:

> Elle et moi, on aime les fruits.

Comment: Normalement le plus juste serait d'ailleurs de dire "Elle et moi aimons les fruits" ou "Nous aimons les fruits".

Comment: @Raiana Plus soutenu sûrement, mais pas plus juste. "On aime" est tout à fait correct, il est deux fois plus courant que "Nous aimons" à l'écrit https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+aime%2Cnous+aimons&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20aime%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnous%20aimons%3B%2Cc0 , et largement plus utilisé à l'oral.