# Why don't we say "J'aime toi" instead of "Je t'aime"?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, pronoms-personnels, pronoms-réfléchis

Why don't we say "J'aime toi" instead of "Je t'aime" I was under the impression that you only use the reflexive pronouns me, te, se ... when you have a reflexive verb where the subject is referring to itself... for example: Je me lave... or when two parties are doing a reciprocal action for example: ils s'aiment. Any explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: The French pronoun system has a lot of words doing double or triple duty. *te* is reflexive or direct or indirect object. See [this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWlLC.png) for more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference between the personal pronouns *te/t'* and *toi* is not that one is reflexive and one isn't. They're chosen based on grammatical rules including the grammatical function of the pronoun, the preceding preposition if any. Whether the pronoun is reflexive only matters for the third person, and only when there is no preposition. The rules are fairly complicated. In this answer, I'll only cover the main cases. See also [Reste-t-il en français des traces du système de cas du latin ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/reste-t-il-en-fran%C3%A7ais-des-traces-du-syst%C3%A8me-de-cas-du-latin/1238#1238) for a historical perspective.

- If the personal pronoun is the **subject** of the clause (and the subject is this single word), it's *je*, *tu*, *il/elle*, *nous*, *vous*, *ils/elles*.

  > **Je** t'aime.
- If the personal pronoun is a direct **complement** ([*complément d'objet direct*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compl%C3%A9ment_d%27objet_direct)), it's *me*, *te*, *le/la*, *nous*, *vous*, *les*, and it is placed before the verb (including any auxiliary), but after *ne* if the sentence is negative.

  > Je **t'**aime.
  >   Je **te** vois.
  >   Je ne **les** ai pas vus.

  A direct complement has no preposition, but some complements that have no preposition are not direct complements. As a rule of thumb, if something is a direct complement, you can change the verb to the passive mood, and the direct complement of the active sentence becomes the subject of the passive sentence. An [*attribut du sujet*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribut_(grammaire)) (complements of verbs that indicate a state, such as *être*) is not a direct complement.
- The “default” form is *moi*, *toi*, *lui/elle*, *nous*, *vous*, *eux/elles*. These forms are used after a **preposition**. These are also the forms for the *attribut du sujet*, among others.

  > Elle pense **à lui**.
  >   Elle parle **de lui**.
  >   Elle vient **avec lui**.
  >   **Lui** et **moi** t'aimons.   *(Not *<strike>Il et je</strike> because the usual subject forms cannot be used in combination with anything else.)*
  >   C'est **toi** que j'aime.   *(attribut du sujet)*
- Sometimes, when the indirect complement is a pronoun, it changes form and is placed before the verb with no preposition.

  - ***à*** + pronoun that stands for a person → *me*, *te*, *lui*, *nous*, *vous*, *leur*. Note that this is identical to the direct-complement form for the first and second person, but not for the third person.

    > Il **me** parle.   (*<strike>Il parle à moi.</strike>)
    >   Il **lui** parle.   (*<strike>Il parle à lui/elle.</strike>)
    >   Il **leur** parle.   (*<strike>Il parle à eux/elles.</strike>)
  - ***à*** + pronoun that stands for a thing (not a person) → *y*.

    > Il pense à son avenir. Il **y** pense.   (But: *Il pense à sa femme. Il pense à elle.*)
  - ***de*** + third-person pronoun that stands for a thing (not a person) → *en*.

    > Il parle de ce sujet. Il **en** parle.  (But: *Il parle de sa femme. Il parle d'elle.*)
    >   Il vient de cette ville. Il **en** vient.

    This substition *de* → *en* is also made when *de* is part of a partitive article. See [When to use the pronoun en?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16893/when-to-use-the-pronoun-en/16894#16894) for more details.
- If the subject and the complement are the same person or thing and the complement does not start with a preposition, then there is a different form for the complement, but only for the third person: *se* (both singular and plural). This includes both **reflexive** verbs and cases where the subject and complement just happen to be the same. This includes direct complements, implicit-*à* indirect complement and *attribut du sujet*. In the plural, this form is used both when each subject performs the action on themselves and when the subjects perform the action on each other.

  > Il **se** voit dans le miroir.   *(He sees himself in the mirror. Contrast: “Il le voit dans le miroir” if he sees another male person.)*
  >   Ils **se** lavent les mains.   *(They are washing their hands.)*
  >   Ils **se** sont rencontrés hier.   *(They met yesterday.)*

Answer (score 2):

These pronouns are indeed used a reflexive way:

> Je me lave
>   Tu te trompes
>   Il s'évanouit
>   ...

but it's not their only use case. They can be used too in non reflexive sentences:

> Je te/le/la/vous/les remercie
>   Tu me/le/la/nous/les raccompagnes
>   Il me/te/le/la/nous/vous/les nourrit
>   ...

In these contexts, *toi* and other pronouns might be used, but only in addition and to emphasize the previous one:

> Je t'aime, toi !
>   Il les a conduits, eux !